# Mood detection using svm and hog features

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, svm

I am using Hog features and svm (one vs one approach ) to find three basic emotions (happy, smile and surprised). I have trained 3 models separately and results are good, but when I integrate them, results vary a lot and can not predict one emotion at a time.
Can anyone tell me how can I integrate all models (xml files) whether my logic of integration is wrong or any other modification needed in SVM parameters.

First load all files

```
CvSVM svm;
    svm.load("neutralSVM.xml");
CvSVM surprised;
    surprised.load("surprised.xml");
```

......
....
feed hog features to predict function

```
int smile_result = smilesvm.predict(fm);
                int sur_result = surprised.predict(fm);

            else if (smile_result == 1 )
                    cout << "surprised" << endl;        

            else
                    cout << "neutral" << endl;
```